# Why FFmpeg decode an mov in ARGB pix_format and save it into a png file, there is color distortion.?

Tags: ffmpeg, color-space, mov

[click here to see the comparing picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiHIj.png)

These two pngs are the 101st frame of an mov file.
The left one is decoded by After Effects. I dropped the mov file into AE, and added it into render queue, saved to Comp2_xxxx.png.
The right one is decoded by ffmpeg cmd "ffmpeg -i input.mov %05d.png".
When I opened them in PhotoShop, we can see the obvious difference between them.
I think there is color distortion in the png decoded by ffmpeg.
Then, why?

[Difference between decoration rendered by AE(left) and rendered by ffmpeg(right)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGlfg.jpg)

Comment: How do they look with alpha matting off i.e. no  checkerboard

Comment: If there is a pure black back ground under it, they look very similar.  --- how ever, we use these flowers to decorate kinds of photos users uploaded. When color of these photos are light, such as white/brown, the edge of the flowers still look terrible.